# How to filter an array of strings from Azure Graph API json response?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to filter out the tags present in the following Azure GRAPH API response:

```
{
     "displayName": "BlazorApp2-AuthenticationAAD",
     "tags": [
     "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"
   ]
 },
```

I want to set a filter for the Rest call to display applications which has the following tag in it. Can someone help me with the Rest call that can be used here to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$filter=tags/any(c:c eq 'WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp')
```

to filter the applications which contain the tag.